# Python lxml the E-Factory

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I've  been using the lxml "E-Factory" (aka. ElementMaker) for creating xml documents.   I'm trying to generate an xml document similar to this:

```
<url>
  <date-added>2011-11-11</date-added>
</url>
```

However, using the E-factory, I'm not sure how to specify the dash in the 'data-added' element.  It seems to be interpreting the dash as a minus sign.

Here is the docs I've been referring to: 
http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-e-factory

Here is how to reproduce the error:

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker 

E = ElementMaker()
URL = E.url
DATE_ADDED = E.date-added

xml = URL(DATE_ADDED(myobject.created.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')),)


NameError global name 'added' is not defined
```

Does anyone know a trick to get it do properly render the element with a dash?

Thank you for reading this.

Joe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ElementMaker` maps a function to a tag name (by using e.g. `E.date_added`) to build up the XML tree. However, there is a discrepancy between the allowed characters in HTML/XML tags and Python functions. As stated in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): *"Package and Module Names Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability"*. So, the `date_added` function includes an underscore, which isn't allowed to be present in a Python function:

```
>>> def foo-bar():
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def foo-bar():
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

To resolve it, just create the `date-added` tag a bit more verbosely by supplying the name as an argument instead:

```
>>> etree.tostring(E.url(E('date-added', '2011-11-11')))
'<url><date-added>2011-11-11</date-added></url>'
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  It seems to work well and helped me view what is happening with the enigmatic "E" object in a different light. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 9):

Explanation: What you put after `E.` needs to be a [valid Python identifier](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers). This includes underscores but not hyphens. `E.date-added` is compiled "successfully" as if it were `(E.date) - added` but then fails at run time because (in your case) `added` was not defined.

Alternatives:

(1) The `E.tag` is just a cosmetic trick that doesn't work with all legal XML tags. In reality Python object attributes can be just about any old rubbish, you just can't do `obj.really+funky%attribute*name,dude` in source code. One dud trick deserves a better trick: You can keep the same pattern of element creation i.e. don't need to specify the tag every time you create an element by doing:

```
DATE_ADDED = getattr(E, 'date-added')
```

and then using `DATE_ADDED` as you do now.

(2) If the schema is under your control, use underscore (date_added) instead of hyphen(date-added).

Comment: Thank you for your solution.  That's a great approach using the getattr method.